# Convert Objects from c# to php for SOAP php

Tags: c#, php, codeigniter

I have problem in getting the right parameter to a certain method that I request.
They gave me a sample of c# sample code on how to implement it.

```
DateTime versionDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2008");
string stateAbbreviation = "CA";
string AuthenticationKey = “MzU=”;

VehicleConfiguration vehicleConfiguration = new VehicleConfiguration();
vehicleConfiguration.Year = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Year.Id = 2005;
vehicleConfiguration.Year.Name = “2005”;
vehicleConfiguration.Make = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Make.Id = 5;
vehicleConfiguration.Make.Name = “BMW”;
vehicleConfiguration.Model = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Model.Id = 5;
vehicleConfiguration.Model.Name = “M3”;
vehicleConfiguration.Trim = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Trim.Id = 151;
vehicleConfiguration.Trim.Name = “Coupe 2D”;
vehicleConfiguration.Engine = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Engine.Id = 5044;
vehicleConfiguration.Engine.Name = “6-Cyl. 3.2 Liter”;
vehicleConfiguration.Drivetrain = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Drivetrain.Id = 5049;
vehicleConfiguration.Drivetrain.Name = “RWD”;
vehicleConfiguration.Transmission = new IdNamePair();
vehicleConfiguration.Transmission.Id = 5049;
vehicleConfiguration.Transmission.Name = “6-Spd SMG”;
vehicleConfiguration.Mileage = 20000;
vehicleConfiguration.VehicleCondition = VehicleCondition.Excellent;

VehicleValuation vehicleValuation = proxy. GetVehicleValuesByVehicleConfiguration(authenticationKey, versionDate, true, stateAbbreviation,vehicleConfiguration)
```

How can I convert this to php.?

I already started to code this one, and I already accessed the other method which has simple parameter.

I'm stuck only at the  part of  "VehicleConfiguration" which is an object I think.

Someone, help me, I'll give credit.

thanks.

Comment: and what is the problem with VehicleConfiguration? Why you stuck?

Comment: probably the way I format VehicleConfiguration is wrong. because of some method that I accessed is working. for example. 

This is how I accessed other method in php.   

         $get_car_mileage->authenticationKey  =  $key;        $get_car_mileage->vehicleType = $car_type;        $get_car_mileage->versionDate =  $var_date;         $get_car_mileage->yearId = $year_id;     $result = $soap_connect->__soapCall('GetZeroPointMileageByYear', array($get_car_mileage));

(This method have no parameters like VehicleConfiguration)

Comment: This is the given example in c# testDate = “01/01/2008”
versionDate = CDate(testDate)
vehicleType = “UsedCar”
yearId = CInt(cboYears.SelectedValue)
AuthenticationKey = “MzU=”


Proxy. GetZeroPointMileageByYear(AuthenticationKey, vehicleType, versionDate,true, yearId,true,  out getMileageResult, out resultSpecified)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dateTime = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("01/01/2008"));
$stateAbbreviation = "CA";
$authenticationKey = "MzU=";

$vehicleConfiguration = new VehicleConfiguration();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($vehicleConfiguration);
echo "</pre>";

class VehicleConfiguration {
    public $Year;
    public $Make;
    public $Model;
    public $Trim;
    public $Engine;
    public $Drivetrain;
    public $Transmission;
    public $Mileage;
    public $VehicleCondition;

    public function  __construct(){
        $this->Year = new IdNamePair(2005, '2005');
        $this->Make = new IdNamePair(5, 'BMW');
        $this->Model = new IdNamePair(5, 'M3');
        $this->Trim = new IdNamePair(151, 'Coupe 2D');
        $this->Engine = new IdNamePair(5044, '6-Cyl. 3.2 Liter');
        $this->Drivetrain = new IdNamePair(5049, 'RWD');
        $this->Transmission = new IdNamePair(5049, '6-Spd SMG');
        $this->Mileage = 20000;
        $this->VehicleCondition = 'Excellent';

        return $this;
    }
}

class IdNamePair{
    public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public function __construct($id = NULL, $name = NULL){
        $this->Id = $id;
        $this->Name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

ana pre?

Comment: Yes, but I used codeigniter. I create a class recently and our code is mostly identical especially in the structure of class.

Answer (score 0):

CLASS vehicleConfiguration (library folder)

```
class vehicleConfiguration {

public $Year;
public $Make;
public $Model;
public $Engine;
public $Transmission;

public $Mileage;
public $VehicleCondition;


    public function __construct()
    {
       // parent::__construct();

        $this->Year = (object) array();
        $this->Make =  (object) array();
        $this->Model =  (object) array();
        $this->Engine =  (object) array();
        $this->Transmission =  (object) array();
        $this->Mileage =  (object) array('Mileage' => '');
        $this->VehicleCondition =  (object) array('VehicleCondition' => '');
    }
    function Mileage($mileage)
    {
        $this->Mileage = $mileage;
    }

    function VehicleCondition($mileage)
    {
        $this->VehicleCondition = $mileage;
    }

}
```

CLASS IdNamePair (library folder)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class IdNamePair {

    public function __construct()
    {
       // parent::__construct();
    }


  function IdNamePair($id, $name)
    {
          $this->Id = $id;
          $this->Name = $name;
    }   
}
```

Class request (Controller)

```
        $this->load->library('vehicleConfiguration');
            $this->load->library('IdNamePair');
$soap_connect = new  SoapClient('http://sample.idws.syndication.kbb.com/VehicleInformationService2008R2.svc?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));


        $trim = $this->input->post('car_id'); //trim ID
        $consumer_category = 'Consumer'; //Consumer, Dealer
        $key =  $this->input->post('Key');
        $var_date =  strtotime($this->input->post('Ver_date'));
        $car_type = $this->input->post('Type');
        $stateAbbrev= "CA"; 

        $get_car_value->authenticationKey  =  $key;
        $get_car_value->versionDate =  $var_date;
        $get_car_value->stateAbbreviation =  $stateAbbrev;

$config =  $this->vehicleconfiguration;

        $config->Year = $this->idnamepair; 

        $config->Make = $this->idnamepair;

        $config->Model = $this->idnamepair;

        $config->Trim = $this->idnamepair;

        $config->Engine = $this->idnamepair;

        $config->Transmission = $this->idnamepair;

        $config->Year->IdNamePair($this->input->post('year'),$this->input->post('year')) ;
        $config->Make->IdNamePair($this->input->post('make'),$this->input->post('make')) ;
        $config->Model->IdNamePair($this->input->post('model'),$this->input->post('model')) ;
        $config->Trim->IdNamePair($this->input->post('car_id'),$this->input->post('car_id')) ;
        $config->Engine->IdNamePair($this->input->post('engine'),$this->input->post('engine')) ;
        $config->Transmission->IdNamePair($this->input->post('trans'),$this->input->post('trans')) ;

$config->Mileage = $this->input->post('mileage');
        $config->VehicleCondition = 'Excellent';

        $params =   array(
         'authenticationKey' => $key,
         'versionDate' => $var_date,
         'stateAbbreviation' => $stateAbbrev,
         'Id' => $this->input->post('car_id'),
          $config
    );
$result = $soap_connect->__soapCall('GetVehicleValuesByVehicleConfiguration', array($params));
```